# Determining if a digraph has any vertex-disjoint cycle cover

Tags: graphs, adjacency-matrix

> Given a digraph, determine if the graph has any vertex-disjoint cycle cover.

I understand that the permanent of the adjacency matrix will give me the number of cycle covers for the graph, which is 0 if there are no cycle covers. But is it possible to check the above condition directly?

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for a more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is answered in the [Wikipedia article on vertex-disjoint cycle covers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cycle_cover). According to the article, you can reduce this problem to that of finding whether a related graph contains a perfect matching. Details can be found in a [paper of Tutte](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/matching/Tutte-short-proof-of-factor-theorem.pdf) or in [recitation notes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f13/recitation/rec1016.txt) of a course given by Avrim Blum.

As a comment, in the graph-theoretic literature a vertex-disjoint cycle cover is known as a *2-factor*.